# Codecademy Loops 8/19

Tags: python, syntax-error

I haven't programmed in a while so I thought I'd continue with my codecademy tutorial to get back into shape. I'm really confused right now because I'm getting all these syntax errors where I'm pretty sure I shouldn't.

Here's my code:

```
from random import randint

# Generates a number from 1 through 10 inclusive
random_number = randint(1, 10)

guesses_left = 3
# Start your game!
while guesses_left > 0:
    guess = int(raw_input("Your guess: ")
    if guess == random_number:
        print "You win!"
        break
    guesses_left = guesses_left - 1
else:
    print "You lose."
```

I'm getting a syntax error because of the colon on line 10.

I don't get why, its an if statement, and after an if statement you always have a colon don't you?

I've been getting a bunch of syntax errors today for simple stuff like this and I don't understand why.

Comment: Please post the actual error traceback!

Answer (score 2):

Is this a straight copy/paste of your code? Your int() is unclosed

```
guess = int(raw_input("Your guess: ")   <--- missing parenthesis
```

Also, the decrement of `guesses_left` is in the wrong place. It should probably be placed after the `else` block, since it should be decremented every loop, regardless of the result of the `if/else`

Further, the indentation on your `else` block doesn't line up with your `if`. Indentation in python is key.

Answer (score 0):

Slight changes to your code:

```
from random import randint

# Generates a number from 1 through 10 inclusive
random_number = randint(1, 10)

guesses_left = 3
# Start your game!
while guesses_left > 0:
    guesses_left = guesses_left - 1
    guess = int(raw_input("Your guess: "))
    if guess == random_number:
        print "You win!"
        break
else:
        print "You lose."
```

Comment: I think its supposed to be a while else block.. If i'm not mistaken this indentation is using if else..

Comment: It's while else because with your code if you guess wrong once it already tells you that you lose..

Comment: Also your guesses_left = guesses_left - 1 line is in the wrong place. With your code it let me guess to infinity. I moved it to just after the line with raw_input and it makes me guess 3 times

Comment: 1) It doesn't go to infinity - maybe it did after you made changes. 2) But yes, it says 'You lose' after every guess. I thought that was what you wanted (i'd have put 'try again' or something similar, before putting in 'You lose'. 3) As you really did want to use while/else I have changed the code accordingly.

Answer (score 0):

This code works and gets you through. The main error I got was that it works but still said there was an error after the game was over. This was due to my else: print 'You lose.' being part of the while operation. Instead have the else: function on the same indentation as the while: , and this is what they wanted to see

```
from random import randint

# Generates a number from 1 through 10 inclusive
random_number = randint(1, 10)

guesses_left = 3

while guesses_left > 0:
    guess = int(raw_input("Your guess: "))
    guesses_left -= 1
    if guess == random_number:
        print "You win!"
        break
else:
    print "You lose."
```

Answer (score 0):

Here is how i did it, I've added some extra features just for fun c:

```
from random import randint

# Generates a number from 1 through 10 inclusive
random_number = randint(1, 10)

print random_number # For debugging

guesses_left = 3 # Amount of guesses left
print "Guess my number! You've got 3 tries left!"

tries = [] # Array for user input

while guesses_left > 0:
    guess = int(raw_input("Your guess: ")) # Asks user to enter a number

    if guess in tries: # Checks if user entered the same number before
        print "You've already guessed this number: ", guess
        print "You've got " , int(guesses_left) , " guess(es) left!"

    elif guess > 10 or guess < 1: # Checks if user input is between 1 and 10
        print "Wrong input! Guess a number between 1 and 10!"
        print "You've got " , int(guesses_left) , " guess(es) left!"

    elif guess == random_number: # If user input is the same as the random number you win!
        print "You win!"
        break

    else:
        guesses_left -= 1 # Decreases the amount of guesses left
        print "You've got " , int(guesses_left) , " guess(es) left!"
        tries.append(guess) # Saves user input to "tries"
else:

    print "You lose!"
```